# Is there an English version of The Typing of the Dead 2?

Tags: the-typing-of-the-dead-2

I liked the first part of The Typing of The Dead, which had an English version, but somehow I cannot find one for part 2.

I understand that the Japanese version supports Latin letters, but all words are in Japanese.

Does some official or unofficial (via mod or patch) English version of The Typing of The Dead 2 exist?

Most sources claim there is none, but they are from 2009.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Wikipedia page for The Typing of the Dead 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Typing_of_the_Dead_2), it was only released for PC in Japan back in 2008. (The arcade version seems to be a Japanese exclusive, as well)

As for unofficial English versions or patches, unfortunately, I have not been able to find any.